# Vectorizing text file in java for kmeans clustering java encog

Tags: java, vectorization, k-means, encog

I am using java encog machine learning library for running kmeans clustering. The problem is that it is possible only on numeric data. Is there a way to vectorize the text file(data) so that I can directly feed into the kmeans clustering algorithm.

I am new to this space. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could be better suited for http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ . However, you have to explain what your entities are, and what distance measure you want to use. If you have several texts, and want to find out a similarity between the texts, one common practice (as far as I know) is to collect ALL words in ALL texts (let this be 100 words) and then create one 100-dimensional vector for each text. This vector has a "1" for the words that are in the text, and a "0" for all other entries.

Answer (score 1):

try using Object Out put Stream 
as follow

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject("YOUR_TEXT");
oos.close();
```